# Is it possible to create two different checkout pages in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Now I am developing an e-commerce website using Worpress. I should create two checkout pages with different inputs and payment methods (one is for instant payment through card and another is for partial payment), but all the data should be represented in one place (Wordpress 'Orders' section). When I have tried to use [woocommerce_checkout] for both of these pages, I could not change their content separately from each other (I have tried to change code inside wordpress/wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\payment-method.php using if(is_page(id)), but it did not work for me).

So, is it possible to create two checkout pages and manage them separately? If yes, how? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: directly changing files from `wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/` folder is bad practice. It's possible to have several checkout pages. but you'll have some php coding experience. will be somethink like if is page -> then. Your question is too broad now